# symmetric bilinear form on $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Find all symmetric bilinear forms of a vector space $V$ of finite dimension on  $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

As every bilinear form is represented by a matrix then the idea is to find the set of matrices representing these transformations, but not how to proceed, I appreciate any hint.

Comment: Hint: What properties of a matrix are sufficient and necessary for it to represent a *symmetric* bilinear form?

Comment: Is necessary that the matrix be symmetric , but not if this is  a  sufficient condition . If so then  would all symmetric matrices ?

Comment: To check whether it's sufficient, you only need to know: Does a symmetric matrix determine a symmetric bilinear form?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Take $V = (\Bbb Z_2)^n$.  Let $M \in \Bbb {Z_2}^{n \times n}$.  Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the canonical basis vectors.  We note that for $M$ to be a symmetric bilinear form, we must have
$$
(e_i)^TMe_j = (e_j)^T M e_i
$$
Why is this condition also sufficient?